# jQuery - Run function only if list is empty

Tags: jquery

Each time I click the `create` button I want to run `inputCheck` and if there are no errors (and the `errorList` is empty) then run the `swal` function to confirm the post. If there are errors, then don't run the alert.

```
$(".btn--post", $this).on("click", function() {
        inputError();
        if (errorList.length == 0) {
          swal({})
        }
      });
```

I only want to run the `swal` function if there are no errors in `errorList`. My current markup however isn't running the `swal` if the `errorList` is empty.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $item = $(".post__item");
  $item.each(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find(".input");
    var $this = $(this);
    var inputCheck = function() {
      var errorList = $("div.details__error", $this);
      var inputError = function() {
        errorList.empty();
        $this.find(":required:invalid").each(function(index, node) {
          var label = $(node).attr("name");
          var message = node.validationMessage || "Invalid value.";
          errorList
            .show()
            .append(
              "<div><span>" + label + ": " + "</span>" + message + "</div>"
            );
        });
      };
      $(".btn--post", $this).on("click", function() {
        inputError();
        if (errorList.length == 0) {
          swal({
            title: "Create Post?",
            text: "You won't be able to make changes to your post later.",
            confirmButtonText: "Post",
            confirmButtonColor: "#6064e6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            reverseButtons: true,
            showCancelButton: true
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
              /*Post Item*/
            } else if (result.dismiss === "cancel") {
              /* swal("Cancelled", "Your stay here :)", "error");*/
            }
          });
        }
      });
    };
    inputCheck();
  });
});
```

```css
.details__icon {
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.post__item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 120px
}

.post__item label {
  height: 146px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="post__item">
    <div class="details__icon"></div>
    <div class="details__error"></div>
    <label>
      <textarea required class="input" name="first" type="text" placeholder="first"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input required class="input" name="second" type="text" placeholder="second">
    </label>
    <button class="btn--post">Create</button>
  </div>
  <div class="post__item">
    <div class="details__icon"></div>
    <div class="details__error"></div>
    <label>
      <textarea required class="input" name="first" type="text" placeholder="first"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input required class="input" name="second" type="text" placeholder="second">
    </label>
    <button class="btn--post">Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does this

```
errorList.empty(); 
errorList.append(..error div..); 
if (errorList.length == 0) { ...
```

In this case `errorList.length` will always be 1 because you're adding entries *inside* `errorList`, not to `errorList` itself.

Change the check to

```
if (errorList.children().length == 0) { ...
```